# Swift: Computed Property - call function when value changed

Tags: swift, computed-properties

I have need of a variable that retains the selected index into an array of objects.

I need to make a function call whenever this index changes.

I had thought that computed properties were the way to go but I'm having problems with recursion

```
var selectedIndex : Int = 0
{
  get
  {
    return self.selectedIndex
  }

  set
  {
    self.selectedIndex = newValue
    self.delegate?.updatedValue()
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: As a general rule, a computed property doesn't have an underlying non computed property. Any reference to `selectedIndex` is just calling the computed property again. The accepted answer is the right thing to do in this instance, but should you need a computed property with a backing property in future, you must separately declare the backing property with a different name. e.g. put an underscore on the front: `_selectedIndex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `didSet` to the stored property.

```
var selectedIndex : Int = 0 {
  didSet {
    self.delegate?.updatedValue()
  }
}
```